# Is it guaranteed to be 2038-safe if sizeof(std::time_t) == sizeof(std::uint64_t) in C++?

Tags: c++, time, standards, year2038, y2k

Excerpted from the [cppref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time):

> Implementations in which `std::time_t` is a 32-bit signed integer (many
> historical implementations) fail in the year 2038.

However, the documentation doesn't say how to detect whether the current implementation is 2038-safe. So, my question is:

**Is it guaranteed to be 2038-safe if** `sizeof(std::time_t) == sizeof(std::uint64_t)` **in C++?**

Comment: (from : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/time_t)
*Although not defined, this is almost always an integral value holding the number of seconds (not counting leap seconds) since 00:00, Jan 1 1970 UTC, corresponding to POSIX time.* That's not a definition I'd like to build my software on, and prefer using std::chrono. I think your real question is: can we get away with compiling to 64bit to avoid having to refactor our code? My recommendation to that is write unit tests for your time handling stuff and test it specialy for dates after and time periods spanning the 2038 problem point.

Comment: Do you want to be compatible across platforms? If *not*, then read the docs of the relevant platform.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Practically speaking **yes**. In all modern implementations in major OSes `time_t` is the number of seconds since POSIX epoch, so if `time_t` is larger than `int32_t` then it's immune to the y2038 problem

You can also check if `__USE_TIME_BITS64` is defined in 32-bit Linux and if `_USE_32BIT_TIME_T` is not defined in 32-bit Windows to know if it's 2038-safe

---

However regarding the C++ standard, things aren't as simple. `time_t` in C++ is defined in `<ctime>` which has the [same content as `<time.h>`](http://eel.is/c++draft/ctime.syn) in C standard. And in C `time_t` isn't defined to have any format

> 3. The types declared are `size_t` (described in [7.19](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.19));
>
> ```
> clock_t
> ```
>
> and
>
> ```
> time_t
> ```
>
> which are real types capable of representing times;
>
> 4. The range and precision of times representable in `clock_t` and `time_t` are implementation-defined
>
> [http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.1p3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.1p3)

So it's permitted for some implementation to have for example `double` as `time_t` and store picoseconds from 1/1 year 16383 BCE, or even a 64-bit integer with only 32 value bits and 32 padding bits. That may be one of the reasons [`difftime()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/difftime) returns a double

To check y2038 issue portably at run time you can use [`mktime`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/c/mktime)

> The `mktime` function returns the specified calendar time encoded as a value of type `time_t`. If the calendar time cannot be represented, the function returns the value `(time_t)(-1)`.
>
> [http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.2.3p3](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.27.2.3p3)

```
struct tm time_str;
time_str.tm_year   = 2039 - 1900;
time_str.tm_mon    = 1 - 1;
time_str.tm_mday   = 1;
time_str.tm_hour   = 0;
time_str.tm_min    = 0;
time_str.tm_sec    = 1;
time_str.tm_isdst = -1;
if (mktime(&time_str) == (time_t)(-1))
    std::cout << "Not y2038 safe\n";
```